# how to use values of consequent rows of grouped data to decide value of current row using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Of the dataset below I want to change the value of the `won_offer` column to either a `1` or a `0`. The problem is that I need the consequent rows of the customer-code combination to decide the value of that column.

If one of the next rows within 30 days of the current row's date contains `order` and the price is lower than the current row's price, the 0 of the `won_offer` column of that row can become a 1.

sample dataset:

```
analysis = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('customer1', 'code1', 'date', 'order', 1.7, 0, 1),
        ('customer1', 'code2', 'date', 'offer', 1.5, 0, 2),
        ('customer1', 'code2', 'date', 'offer', 2.0, 0, 2),
        ('customer2', 'code1', 'date', 'offer', 1.2, 0,4),
        ('customer2', 'code1', 'date', 'order', 1.1, 0,4),
        ('customer2', 'code1', 'date', 'order', 2.0, 0,4),
        ('customer2', 'code1', 'date', 'offer', 1.2, 0,4)
    ],
    ('customer', 'code', 'order_date', 'type', 'price', 'final_offer', 'counter')
)
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work, since I don't know how to pass multiple rows to my udf:

```
w = \
    Window.partitionBy('customer','code').orderBy('orderoffer_date')

@F.udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def logic_udf(counter, curr_date, next_dates, current_type, next_types, curr_price, next_prices) :
    for i in range(len(counter)):
        if (next_dates[i] < curr_date+30):
            if (next_types[i] == 'order') & (next_prices[i] < curr_price ):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return 0

analysis = analysis.withColumn('won_offer', 
               logic(analysis.counter, analysis.order_date,lead(analysis.order_date, 
               analysis.n).over(w), analysis.type,lead(analysis.type, 
               analysis.n).over(w), analysis.price, lead(analysis.price, 
               analysis.n).over(w)))
```

desired output:

```
desired_result = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('customer1', 'code1', 'date', 'order', 1.7, 0, 1),
        ('customer1', 'code2', 'date', 'offer', 1.5, 0, 2),
        ('customer1', 'code2', 'date', 'offer', 2.0, 0, 2),
        ('customer2', 'code1', 'date', 'offer', 1.2, 1, 4),
        ('customer2', 'code1', 'date', 'order', 1.1, 1, 4),
        ('customer2', 'code1', 'date', 'order', 1.0, 0, 4),
        ('customer2', 'code1', 'date', 'offer', 1.2, 0, 4)
    ],
    ('customer', 'code', 'order_date', 'type', 'price', 'final_offer', 'counter')
)
```

I realize my question is quite complex. **If someone could just tell me how I could pass multiple rows of grouped data to a udf**, I would already be helped a lot.

In short: the main goal is to decide the value of a column in a row by looking at multiple columns in the next rows (and still within their specific group).

Thanks in Advance!
Charles

Answer (score 1):

You can use window with sql functions to replace logic_udf. Since You are only use first row after the current row you can add first row after current row to current row.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

analysis \
    .withColumn('next_order_date', F.first('order_date').over(w)) \
    .withColumn('next_type', F.first('type').over(w)) \
    .withColumn('next_price', F.first('price').over(w)) \
    .withColumn('won_offer', F.when(condition, 1).otherwise(0))
```

Comment: Seems elegant, thank you! What does the **first** function do? and does it return a vector that I can iterate over?

Comment: First function take first element of grouped data.